# Make app uncloseable/disable CMD+Q on mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I have gotten in the habit of pressing CMD+Q instead of just switching windows on one app I use very frequently. I want to make the app uncloseable or at least disable CMD+Q for just that app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, found [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) works well to redirect CMD+Q to CMD+H only on the simulatot

Comment: You should accept your own answer since you consider this problem solved. You can also edit the question so that the answer fits better and could help others.

Comment: This solution costs money. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was free at the time, try finding an alternative (try alternativeto.net)